# Can an exe file compiled with Delphi 7 work on OSX?

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-7, macos-sierra, recompile

I have an exe file compiled with Delphi 7. I want it to work on OSX (in this case, Mac OS Sierra). Is there any way to compile the exe file as an OSX package and install/run it on OSX?

Comment: Converting to Firemonkey is not an option ?

Comment: @user763539 i thought that too but it will take too long of time, in this case wine enumator working fine, but maybe changing language and making programs cross platrom seems a nice option too (maybe using github framework electron)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi 7 can produce only Windows executables. Your only possibility to run the executable on OSX is to run it under the WINE emulator. Whether or not it will run correctly under WINE depends on what the program actually does. You will just have to try it and see what happens.